# Ajax lazy loading, accordion button not activated

Tags: javascript, jquery, ajax, wordpress

I'm lazy loading pages in Wordpress using Ajax. Everything is working fine apart from my accordion buttons. If you access the page directly it works fine, but if you come from another page and the accordion page is lazy loaded the buttons wont' be active, though the content will be present in the source.

Using Javascript, is it possible to initialize this button?

I can't post the link although I've included a screenshot of the source that handles it.

[The Accordion](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Zi8ka.png)

[Unexpanded](https://i.stack.imgur.com/GOx0H.png)

[Expanded](https://i.stack.imgur.com/HyJtz.png)

I am completely new to JS, I'm really not sure how I can handle this. Does anyone have any insight?

EDIT:

I've since written this

```
<script>
jQuery(function($) {
$('omsc-accordion').click(function() {
    $('.omsc-accordion').addClass('.omsc-toggle omsc-expanded');
})
});
</script>
```

But it does nothing. Shold this be working? I'm brand new to jQuery

Comment: $('omsc-accordion').click(function() dot is missing from the selector. it should be $('.omsc-accordion').click(function()

Answer (score 0):

Since content is loaded via AJAX, try another way to access click handler

```
$(document).on('click', '.omsc-accordion', function() {
    $(this).addClass('omsc-toggle omsc-expanded');
});
```

Comment: Thanks, though it still isn't doing anything. Are you basing that entirely off the code I wrote above, or from the screenshots? I'm not even sure if what I'm doing is right to begin with.

Comment: as I can can see on your code you added extra dot `addClass('.omsc-toggle omsc-expanded');` have to be `addClass('omsc-toggle omsc-expanded');`